# What is the maximum file size we can upload for custom lightning upload not the standrad one?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have seen people giving maximum file size of 4.5 MB for custom lightning upload. I want to get confirmation for the same. Anyone who knows can you please let me know. With custom lightning upload I mean:

```
<lightning:input type="file">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum size that you can upload using the [`lightning:input`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/documentation) as documented is 1MB unless you chunk the files to be able to load 4MB.

> Files uploaded using `type="file"` are subject to a 1 MB size limit, or about 4 MB if you chunk the files. You must wire up your component to an Apex controller that handles file uploads. Alternatively, use the `lightning:fileUpload` component for an integrated way to upload files to records.

With [`lightning:fileUpload`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:fileUpload/documentation), you can upload a file size of maximum 2GB.

Comment: Thank you so much for the confirmation. It clears my doubt. Marking it as a best answer

Comment: +1 . You can select larger files in ` lightning:input`, its just you wont be able to transport them to apex.