# File upload - heap size too large

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components

I have component inside visualforce page. it working in lightning out. There is lightning:input file in the component. When I upload files larger than 1.7 MB server throws error: Apex heap size too large: 7954798. I know enabled heap size is 6 MB, but why I receive this error with files for example 2 MB size? 
My JS helper:

```
({
    MAX_FILE_SIZE: 4718592, //Max file size 4.5 MB
    CHUNK_SIZE: 750000,      //Chunk Max size 750Kb

    init: function(component, event, helper) {

        const action = component.get('c.getWorkOrder');
        action.setParams({
            woId: component.get('v.workOrderId'),
        });

        action.setCallback(this, (response) => {
        const respState = response.getState();
            if (respState === 'SUCCESS') {
                const workOrder = response.getReturnValue();
                component.set('v.workOrder', workOrder);

                let isCompleted = false;
                if (typeof (workOrder.Site_Survey__c) !== 'undefined' && workOrder.Site_Survey__r.Completed__c) {
                    isCompleted = true;
                }
                component.set('v.surveyCompleted', isCompleted);

                if (!isCompleted) {
                    const flow = component.find("flowData");
                    const inputVariables = [
                    {
                        name : 'recordId',
                        type : 'String',
                        value : component.get('v.workOrderId'),
                    }
                    ];
                    flow.startFlow("Site_Survey_Form", inputVariables);
                }
            }
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },

    statusChangeHelper: function(component, event) {
        let status = event.getParam('status');
        component.set('v.flowStatus', status);

        let currentStage = event.getParam('currentStage');
        let currentStageLabel = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(currentStage.label));
        component.set('v.currentStage', currentStageLabel);

        console.log('current stage: ' + currentStageLabel);

        if(currentStageLabel == 'Finish_Stage') {
            component.set('v.surveyCompleted', true);
        }        
    },

    fileChange: function (component, event) {
        let fileName = '';
        let files = event.getSource().get("v.files");

        if (files.length > 0) {
            for(let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                if (files[i].size > this.MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
                    fileName =  'Alert : File size cannot exceed ' + this.MAX_FILE_SIZE / 1048576 + ' Mb.\n' + 
                                    ' Selected file ' + '\"' + files[i].name + '\"' + ' size: ' + 
                                    Math.round((files[i].size / 1048576) * 100) / 100 + 'Mb';
                    break;
                } else {
                    fileName += files[i].name;
                    if(i < files.length - 1) fileName += ', ';
                }

            }
        }

        if(fileName == '') {
            component.set("v." + event.getSource().get('v.name'), 'No File Selected..');
        } else {
            component.set("v." + event.getSource().get('v.name'), fileName);
        }
    },

    uploadHelper: function(component, event) {
        let self = this;
        let fileInput = [];

        if (component.find("fileId1") && component.find("fileId1").get("v.files")) {
            let fileList = component.find("fileId1").get("v.files");
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(fileList, file => {
                fileInput.push(file);
                console.log('file.size:' + file.size);
            });
        }

        fileInput.forEach((f) => {
            let objFileReader = new FileReader();

            objFileReader.onload = $A.getCallback(() => {
                let fileContents = objFileReader.result;
                var base64 = 'base64,';
                var dataStart = fileContents.indexOf(base64) + base64.length;

                fileContents = fileContents.substring(dataStart);

                self.uploadProcess(component, f, fileContents);
            });

            objFileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
        });      
    },

    uploadProcess: function(component, file, fileContents) {
        // set a default size or startpostiton as 0
        var startPosition = 0;
        // calculate the end size or endPostion using Math.min() function which is return the min. value
        var endPosition = Math.min(fileContents.length, startPosition + this.CHUNK_SIZE);
        // start with the initial chunk, and set the attachId(last parameter)is null in begin
        this.uploadInChunk(component, file, fileContents, startPosition, endPosition, '');
    },

    uploadInChunk: function(component, file, fileContents, startPosition, endPosition, attachId) {
        // call the apex method 'saveChunk'
        var getchunk = fileContents.substring(startPosition, endPosition);
        console.log('start:' + startPosition + ', end:' + endPosition);
        var action = component.get("c.saveChunk");
        action.setParams({
            parentId: component.get("v.workOrder").Site_Survey__c,
            fileName: file.name,
            base64Data: encodeURIComponent(getchunk),
            contentType: file.type,
            fileId: attachId
        });

        // set call back
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            // store the response / Attachment Id
            attachId = response.getReturnValue();
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                // update the start position with end postion
                startPosition = endPosition;
                endPosition = Math.min(fileContents.length, startPosition + this.CHUNK_SIZE);
                // check if the start postion is still less then end postion
                // then call again 'uploadInChunk' method ,
                // else, diaply alert msg and hide the loading spinner
                if (startPosition < endPosition) {
                    this.uploadInChunk(component, file, fileContents, startPosition, endPosition, attachId);
                } else {
                    //alert('your File is uploaded successfully');
                    component.set("v.showLoadingSpinner", false);
                }
            // handel the response errors
            } else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
                alert("From server: " + response.getReturnValue());
            } else if (state === "ERROR") {
                var errors = response.getError();
                if (errors) {
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        console.log("Error message: " + errors[0].message);
                    }
                } else {
                console.log("Unknown error");
                }
            }
        });
        // enqueue the action
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

My Apex Controller:

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static Id saveChunk(Id parentId, String fileName, String base64Data, String contentType, String fileId) {
        // check if fileId id ''(Always blank in first chunk), then call the saveTheFile method,
        //  which is save the check data and return the attachemnt Id after insert,
        //  next time (in else) we are call the appentTOFile() method
        //   for update the attachment with reamins chunks
        if (fileId == '') {
            fileId = saveTheFile(parentId, fileName, base64Data, contentType);
        } else {
            appendToFile(fileId, base64Data);
        }

        return Id.valueOf(fileId);
    }

    public static Id saveTheFile(Id parentId, String fileName, String base64Data, String contentType) {
        base64Data = EncodingUtil.urlDecode(base64Data, 'UTF-8');

        Attachment oAttachment = new Attachment();
        oAttachment.parentId = parentId;

        oAttachment.Body = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(base64Data);
        oAttachment.Name = fileName;
        oAttachment.ContentType = contentType;

        insert oAttachment;

        return oAttachment.Id;
    }

    private static void appendToFile(Id fileId, String base64Data) {
        base64Data = EncodingUtil.urlDecode(base64Data, 'UTF-8');

        Attachment a = [
                SELECT Id, Body
                FROM Attachment
                WHERE Id =: fileId
        ];

        String existingBody = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(a.Body);

        a.Body = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(existingBody + base64Data);

        update a;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This was previously [answered](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/274303/what-is-the-maximum-file-size-we-can-upload-for-custom-lightning-upload-not-the#:~:text=1%20Answer&text=The%20maximum%20size%20that%20you,if%20you%20chunk%20the%20files.), it seems that it was cap to 1MB. The previous answer mentions [lightning:fileUpload](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:fileUpload/documentation) for larger files or chunking the file.

Comment: Yes I use chunks, fileUpload not working in lightning out

Comment: Then I believe would be good to add this into your question and explain how the chunking is performed. That may shed light for me or others to help you further.