# How to resize the <lightning-file-upload> modal on a phone in lightning web component?

Tags: lightning-web-components, modal, lightning-file-upload

I'm trying to resize the standard modal which is shown after I click on the  < lightning-file-upload > tag and select images.

The reason for this is because when a page is zoomed in on a phone browser and user clicks on this tag, the modal will appear too enlarged and user won't be able to click any button and scroll anywhere.

Is there a good way to reduce the size of this modal?

this is the Upload Files modal

[image]

Comment: can you tell the os android/IOS? or is  it for both?

Comment: @AbhinavThakur This problem only appears on IOS.

Comment: Strange! as per this KI [lightning-file-upload is not supported by Android webview](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001HgCMQA0)

Answer (score 0):

Not the direct answer to your question. However, I think you can try with `<lightning:input type="file">` alternative for  `lightning-file-upload`
which should not give issue with phone browser.

```
<template>
    <lightning-input type="file"
                     label="Attachment"
                     accept="image/png, .zip"
                     onchange={handleFilesChange}
                     multiple>
    </lightning-input>
</template>
```

> lightning-input type="file" handles file selection only and you must
> have your own file upload implementation, such as wiring up your
> component to an Apex controller that handles file uploads.
> Alternatively, use the lightning-file-upload component for an
> integrated way to upload files to records.

Update

Though with this approach there would be limitations around file size as @kawadragon also noted that.

Check [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/274303/what-is-the-maximum-file-size-we-can-upload-for-custom-lightning-upload-not-the#:%7E:text=The%20maximum%20size%20that%20you,controller%20that%20h) for limitations.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this solution, but I could not use this tag because the file data size limit of lightning:input is smaller than lightning-file-upload.

Comment: Yes , was aware , I should have mentioned that. Will update that to answer.